# How to solve apply.split error in a dataframe?

Tags: python, error-handling, data-analysis

In this data set, I am trying to split all data having '/' which are apparently existing in 79 rows, as follow :

`df1_18['cmb_mpg'].str.contains('/').sum()`
`df1_18['hwy_mpg'].str.contains('/').sum()`
`df1_18['city_mpg'].str.contains('/').sum()`
`df1_18['fuel'].str.contains('/').sum()`

the output in the 4 of them is 79
[picture of dataframe objects separated by '/'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5DjU.png)

but when i use the apply method,
"""

## list of columns to split

split_columns = ['fuel','city_mpg','hwy_mpg','cmb_mpg']

## apply split function to each column of each dataframe copy

for c in split_columns:

```
df1_18[c] = df1_18[c].apply(lambda x: x.split("/")[0])
df2_18[c] = df2_18[c].apply(lambda x: x.split("/")[1])
```

"""

it gives me that error'index out of range. any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Post sample data

Comment: Edit the question, not in comments

Comment: Please post sample data i.e. part of the "df" to understand why their is this error